# ¿Cómo adquirió la expresión "abrírsele las carnes a alguien" su significado actual?

Tags: modismos, significado, españa

Antiguamente, la expresión "abrírsele las carnes a alguien" se tomaba de forma totalmente literal:

> *Pecten. tinis. masculino genero me. cor. in obliquo. el peyne o vn instrumento de fierro con dientes o forma de peyne con que abrian las carnes alos martires.*
>
> Rodrigo Fernández de Santaella, "Vocabulario eclesiástico", 1499 (España).

Y cuando digo literal, también me refiero al hecho de que se usaba para decir que se infligían heridas:

> *¡Ay, ansiada fue yo! No me des tan crudamente, que me abres las carnes.*
>
> Gaspar Gómez de Toledo, "Tercera parte de la tragicomedia de Celestina", 1536 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Pero querría yo saber de la señora mi señora doña Dulcinea del Toboso adónde aprendió el modo de rogar que tiene: viene a pedirme que me abra las carnes a azotes, y llámame "alma de cántaro" y "bestión indómito", con una tiramira de malos nombres, que el diablo los sufra.*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "Segunda parte del ingenioso caballero don Quijote de la Mancha", 1615 (España).

Y de hecho, esto se demuestra en la definición de la expresión en el *Diccionario de autoridades*:

> Abrir las *carnes*. Es romper el pelléjo del hombre ò animál, dandole golpes y hiriéndole.

Sin embargo, con el tiempo su significado adquirió un significado más figurado, al punto de que a día de hoy significa:

> [**abrírsele** a alguien **las carnes**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7bnjWlr#7gDj3zE)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Estremecerse de horror.

Ni rastro del significado anterior. Ejemplo:

> *Le aseguro a usted que se me abren las carnes así que habla de irse.*
>
> Fernán Caballero (Cecilia Böhl de Faber), "La gaviota", 1849 (España).

¿Cuándo tuvo lugar este cambio del significado literal al figurado? ¿Cuál fue el motivo del cambio? ¿Por qué la RAE no ha mantenido el significado previo?

Comment: *«¿Por qué la RAE no ha mantenido el significado previo?»* Supongo que no tiene sentido definir un significado literal ya que las propias palabras que componen la expresión nos lo dan.

Comment: @blonfu entiendo lo que dices, pero se me hace raro este caso dado que la expresión tenía un significado tanto literal antes que el figurado. Si solo fuera el literal, entendería que no apareciera en el diccionario (de hecho, en muchas versiones del DLE no aparece esta expresión). Pero ahora existen ambos (aunque uno pueda estar en desuso), y al definir solo el figurado parece que el literal no ha lugar, cuando sí lo tiene.

Answer (score 1):

El significado figurativo relacionado con el sufrimiento no físico, horror, o indignación extrema solo funciona en su forma reflexiva, y proviene directamente de su significado literal como sentimiento de dolor de una herida por maltrato cuando se usa de forma transitiva. Entiendo que existan los dos dependiendo del contexto y la forma.

> " Se me abren las carnes cada vez que recuerdo aquella vez en Mónaco, cuando mi hermano y yo fuimos injustamente detenidos por aquel nimio malentendido en el Casino de Montecarlo. "
>
> " El tío Basilio dio finalmente con el misterioso ladrón de sandías y le abrió las carnes a palos una fatídica noche de agosto."