# ¿Cuándo estableció la RAE que se debía escribir 'e' en vez de 'y' ante palabras que comenzaran por 'i'?

Tags: ortografía, historia, conjunciones

Hoy día existe la regla de escribir *e* como conjunción en vez de *y* si la palabra a continuación comienza con un sonido *i*:

> Dentro de este ambiente confuso e incierto, los mercados bursátiles españoles registraron...

Sin embargo, a raiz de la definición de "abrir las carnes" del *Diccionario de autoridades* vista [en otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23110/12637), sabemos que esto no siempre fue así.

> *... so pena que el que lo cortare y el official que lo cosiere caygan y incurran en pena de cincuenta mill maravedis...* (1560)
>
> *Mas catorçe onzas de pastillas y incienso a dos rreales cada onza.* (1622)
>
> *... y desde ahora los ha por especificados y inclusos en ella por más aumento de dote de la susodicha...* (1742)

Hay textos más recientes, pero ya menos en comparación con los que se encuentran de antes de 1750. Así que pensaba que la norma de escribir 'e' en vez de 'y' era algo relativamente reciente, pero veo que no, ya que los casos de 'e' también son muy numerosos antes de 1700:

> *... donde duramente es acusada e increpada por sus crueldades y se denuncia por descomulgada por sus atrevimientos.* (1508)
>
> *... a despecho de tantos inconvenientes e incomodidades...* (1605)
>
> *... infinitas gracias al cielo de que se ayan sujetado aquellas provincias antes bárbaras e incultas...* (1701)

Visto lo visto, parece que hasta un determinado momento la gente escribía la conjunción que quería al no haber una regla clara: unos evitaban la cacofonía y otros no. De hecho, Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611 ya decía esto sobre la letra *e*:

> ... y con algun primor usamos della quando la diccion que se le sigue empieça en i.

Y la RAE en el *Diccionario de autoridades* dice:

> En lo antiguo se usaba comunmente de la E como conjunción copulativa, tomando el origen del *Et* Latino [...], en cuyo lugar se ha substituido la *y*; aunque el dia de oy se conserva el uso con elegáncia quando la dicción que se le sigue comienza con *i* para evitar la colusion.

Es decir, cambiar *y* por *e* no era una norma, sino algo considerado como culto pero no necesario. El caso es, que parece que hasta la propia RAE usaba *y* antes de palabras que comenzaban por sonido *i* (no sería demasiado culta), así que ¿cuándo decidieron establecer la regla para evitar siempre la cacofonía?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La primera aparición "oficial" de la regla se da en la [octava edición de la *Ortografía* de la Real Academia Española, de 1815](https://books.google.es/books?id=l3bQeY93SgAC&dq=ortografia%20castellana&hl=es&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=conjuncion&f=false), página 30, dentro del epígrafe correspondiente a la letra E:

[image]

> Antiguamente se usó de la *e* como conjuncion en lugar de la *i*; pero hoy la sostituye solamente cuando por comenzar en *i* la palabra que sigue, se perderia ó confundiría la conjuncion en la concurrencia de unas mismas vocales, y para evitar esta cacofonía se escribe *Juan é Ignacio*, *padre é hijo*.

Si nos vamos a la edición anterior, [la séptima (de 1800)](https://books.google.es/books?id=sd5DAAAAcAAJ&dq=ortografia%20castellana&hl=es&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q=conjuncion&f=false), podemos comprobar que no se hace mención de esta regla:

[image]

Y las ediciones y tratados de décadas anteriores se limitan a repetir *verbatim* la nota del *Diccionario de autoridades* que tú mismo citas al final de la pregunta.

Existen manuales ligeramente anteriores a 1815, supuestamente validados por la RAE y que ya incluyen la norma, como por ejemplo [éste de 1813 de Antonio Cortés](https://books.google.es/books?id=eu4jh132Oj4C&dq=ortografia%20castellana&hl=es&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q=conjuncion&f=false) en la página 87 y siguiente.
Pero, puesto que la pregunta es cuándo lo estableció la RAE oficialmente, la respuesta es: **1815**.